# UICollectionView CellForItemAt being called multiple times on scroll causing cell text to overlap

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view that presents an array of dates. When the view first loads, the cells look fine, but after I scroll even a bit horizontally, it appears that the CellForItemAt method is firing off every time, rather than just once, resulting in the cells having overlapping text from their default values. I posted some screenshots below:

Initially, how all the views appear and should look:
[image]

After scrolling a little bit: 
[image]

After scrolling a lot:
[image]

Here is my CellForItemAt code (It is very messy from trial and error):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let dateCell = calenderView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "dateCell", for: indexPath)
    dateCell.layer.cornerRadius = 7
    let dayLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: dateCell.frame.width, height: dateCell.frame.height / 2))
    dayLabel.text = "\(Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: dates[indexPath.row]).day!)"
    let weekdayLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: dateCell.frame.height / 2, width: dateCell.frame.width, height: dateCell.frame.height / 2))
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "EEE", options: 0, locale: NSLocale.current)
    weekdayLabel.text = formatter.string(from: dates[indexPath.row])
    dayLabel.text = "\(Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: dates[indexPath.row]).day!)"
    weekdayLabel.textAlignment = .center
    weekdayLabel.font = weekdayLabel.font.withSize(10)
    dayLabel.textAlignment = .center
    dateCell.addSubview(dayLabel)
    dateCell.addSubview(weekdayLabel)
    return dateCell
}
```

Comment: Cells are reused. Don't do `addSubview()` in `cellForItemAt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of cell resuing , don't add subviews in `cellForRow`

```
dateCell.addSubview(dayLabel)
dateCell.addSubview(weekdayLabel)
```

//

in `cellForRowAt`

```
if indexPath.row == indexOfGray {
  //  gray color
}
else {
{
  // default color 
}
```

design will be either in xib , or custom class of the cell in init method

Comment: Yup this worked! Thank you! Do you know how I could make it so that only one specific cell at a specific index is a dark gray color to show it is that day of the week? I am running into a similar issue where some cells also turn a dark gray color when I scroll.